# Calling JS from .Net code no longer works after updating Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly, javascript-interop

The following was working just fine under VS 2022 v17.7.6 (and still is on another PC). However under VS 2022 v17.8.2 I get an error.

In .cs code behind:

```
[Inject] IJSRuntime? JSRT { get; set; }
DotNetObjectReference<GraphicalUngrouped>? objectReference;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender) await BundleAndSendDotNetHelper();
}

private async Task BundleAndSendDotNetHelper()
{
    objectReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    if (JSRT != null)
    {
        await JSRT.InvokeAsync<string>("SetDotNetHelper", objectReference);
    }
}
```

In the .razor page

```
<script>
    function SetDotNetHelper(dotNetHelper) {
        window.dotNetHelper = dotNetHelper;
    }
</script>
```

This was working. Now I get the following error:

> ```
>  Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'SetDotNetHelper' ('SetDotNetHelper' was undefined).
> ```

```
  Error: Could not find 'SetDotNetHelper' ('SetDotNetHelper' was undefined).
      at https://localhost:7211/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:328
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)...
```

Not sure if it makes any difference but the code is in a component on a page.

Can anyone offer any insights, or suggestions please?

Oh, this is .Net Core 6 in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-location) related:

> Don't place a  tag in a Razor component file (.razor) because
> the  tag can't be updated dynamically by Blazor.

Try to move your js codes from razor component to `_Layout.cshtml` in the `<body>` markup and check if it would work now

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try when I get a chance. 2 things however. 1. I'm using Blazor so there is no _Layout.cshtml, and 2. It doesn't explain why it worked under an older version of Visual Studio but not now.

Comment: For the template that don't have  _layout,move your js codes to _Host.cshtml,if it still couldn't work,please let us know

Comment: Blazor templates don't have ANY .cshtml files.